# Finding the map seed of a Civilization V game

Tags: civilization-5

I recently started a game on Civilization V and I really like the map I'm playing. I know it's possible to manually input a seed when creating a game but is there a way to display the seed of a game in progress?

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen a spot to specify the map seed, and I'm not aware of any location where the value is displayed on a running map.  I will admit to not having total recall of every Civ5 option/value/checkbox/dialog/etc, though ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about getting the seed from an existing map, but you can save only the map and then replay it with different settings.

> In the MODS section, click Single Player. Select Set Up Game. The Map
>   should be selectable here.

http://forums.civfanatics.com/showthread.php?t=387782

Answer (score 2):

Now, there is no way to save the seed, but I found a way to restart on the same map. I recently messed up pretty bad because I had an amazing start for the pantheon "Earth Mother" but I went with "God of the Open Sky" instead. Filled with immediate regret for my action, I looked for any way to reset my pantheon or simply reset the game (I hadn't been smart enough to do a first turn save). I had no save file for the game but as it turns out, buried in the game's files, it has a background autosave for the most recently played game, regardless of your autosave preference settings.

I ended up restoring my session and righting my wrong by going to the C: drive (where I keep my x86 Program Files), going to Program Files, Steam, steamapps, common, and that is where I found my Civilization V folder. Once there I went to the folder marked "saves", the subfolder "single", and the subfolder "auto", wherein I found something titled OldAutoSave_Initial_0000 etc. etc., copy/pasted it into the folder "Single", and upon entering the single player menu and going to Load Game that I had a game titled that long title which turned out to be the start of the match I'd blundered. Ergo I saved my own ass, because this may be the best start I've ever seen. :)

T'was quite the adventure.