# How do I reuse a map in a different game?

Tags: civilization-5

I was playing a very nice map that I liked in Civ V, but a bug in the turn system due to the war I was participating in unfortunately caused me to abandon that game save and world, forcing me to start a new world. That world had a very nice map layout which I loved.

I would like to restart that world using the same seed, but I can't find a way to. Does anyone know how to do this?

Sadly, I don't have a game save prior to when the game-breaking bug occurred.

Comment: Why did you rollback my changes? You just brought back all of the errors I fixed for you...

Comment: Sorry like to pratice my own grammar.

Comment: Okay, but you didn't fix everything. In the future, do not rollback changes just to redo them yourself.

Comment: Related: [Finding the map seed of a Civilization V game](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/138289/122).

Comment: I search that in the search bar and nothing came up so where did you find it?